# How to check if a class is explicitly non-sealed?

Tags: java, java-17, sealed

Is it possible to check if a class is explicitly marked as `non-sealed` like with `MyClass.class.isSealed()` and **without** checking its parent hierarchy? (And if so, how?)

Reason - I want to know if the info is somewhere in the class itself and not guess by checking if its final and looking up the parents. Maybe the language changes one day and this indirect condition may too.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve using this and why is their a restriction over not accessing the parent hierarchy?

Comment: I want to know if the information is explicitly stored somewhere like for all the other `.is...()` methods and the `java.lang.reflect.Modifier` `int`.

Comment: Still doesn't answer why without the parent hierarchy?

Comment: It does. I want to know if the info is somewhere in the class itself and not guess by checking if its final and looking up the parents. Maybe the language changes one day and this indirect condition may too.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are trying to achieve if you had this information; this seems mostly a "satisfy my curiosity about how the world works" question (in which case you probably should have asked it differently.)

Comment: I came across this while writing a ClassChecker that chains multiple checks for the properties of a `Class` instance together, like: is it public, and not abstract and not final, etc. I have incoorporated all possible modifiers from `java.lang.reflect.Modifier` as well as all `.is...()`-checks from `java.lang.Class` and wondered why there is not explicit `isNonSealed()` method.

I dont know if there is an actual use case yet, but I wanted to be exhaustive in my utility class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no dedicated method to find out whether a given class is explicitly defined as `non-sealed` and negating the result of `isSealed` method does not give you an accurate answer.

If you know the rules of defining a class as `non-sealed`, you can construct the method that would do it for you.

- The examined `class`/`interface` must **not** be `final`.
- The examined `class`/`interface` must **not** be `sealed`
- If the examined class is `class`, its direct superclass must be `sealed`.
- If the examined class is `interface`, one of the direct superclasses must be `sealed`.

You don't need to check the whole parent hierarchy but due to the definition of `non-sealed`, you have to inspect its **direct** supertype (or supertypes in case of `interface`).

```java
private static boolean isNonSealed(Class<?> clazz) {
    final boolean extendsSealedInterface = clazz.isInterface() && Arrays.stream(clazz.getInterfaces()).anyMatch(Class::isSealed);
    final boolean extendsSealedClass = clazz.getSuperclass() != null && clazz.getSuperclass().isSealed();

    return !clazz.isSealed()
        && (extendsSealedInterface || extendsSealedClass)
        && !Modifier.isFinal(clazz.getModifiers());
}
```

In a small test, only `Reptile` and `Cat` are and should be found `non-sealed`:

```java
List<Class<?>> classes = List.of(
    Animal.class, Mammal.class, Reptile.class, 
    Dog.class, Cat.class, SiameseCat.class);

classes.forEach(clazz -> {
    System.out.printf("%10s : isSealed = %5s, parent.isSealed=%5s, isFinal=%5s -> isNonSealed=%s%n",
        clazz.getSimpleName(),
        clazz.isSealed(),
        clazz.getSuperclass().isSealed(),
        Modifier.isFinal(clazz.getModifiers()),
        isNonSealed(clazz));
});
```

- **Classes**:

  ```java
  // Let's omit 'permits' as all the subclasses are in the same file.
  static sealed class Animal {}
  static sealed class Mammal extends Animal {}
  static non-sealed class Reptile extends Animal {}
  static final class Dog extends Mammal {}
  static non-sealed class Cat extends Mammal {}
  static class SiameseCat extends Cat {}
  ```

  Output, as you see, only `Reptile` and `Dog` are `non-sealed`:

  > ```
  >     Animal : isInterface=false, isSealed =  true, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=false
  >     Mammal : isInterface=false, isSealed =  true, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed= true, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=false
  >    Reptile : isInterface=false, isSealed = false, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed= true, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=true
  >        Dog : isInterface=false, isSealed = false, isFinal= true, parentClass.isSealed= true, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=false
  >        Cat : isInterface=false, isSealed = false, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed= true, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=true
  > SiameseCat : isInterface=false, isSealed = false, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=false
  > ```
- **Interfaces**:

  ```java
  sealed interface Animal {}
  sealed interface Mammal extends Animal {}
  non-sealed interface Reptile extends Animal {}
  static final class Dog implements Mammal {}     // doggo remains a class
  non-sealed interface Cat extends Mammal {}
  interface SiameseCat extends Cat {}
  ```

  Output:

  > ```java
  >     Animal : isInterface= true, isSealed =  true, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=false
  >     Mammal : isInterface= true, isSealed =  true, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed= true -> isNonSealed=false
  >    Reptile : isInterface= true, isSealed = false, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed= true -> isNonSealed=true
  >        Dog : isInterface=false, isSealed = false, isFinal= true, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed= true -> isNonSealed=false
  >        Cat : isInterface= true, isSealed = false, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed= true -> isNonSealed=true
  > SiameseCat : isInterface= true, isSealed = false, isFinal=false, parentClass.isSealed=false, parentInterfaces.anyIsSealed=false -> isNonSealed=false
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an inbuilt way to do that currently.

When you are creating your own method, you should make sure to check that the class is not `final` to isolate only the cases where the class is explicitly marked non-sealed:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {
  public static boolean isExplicitlyNonSealed(Class<?> clazz) {
    boolean isClassSealed = clazz.isSealed();
    boolean isSuperSealed = clazz.getSuperclass() != null && clazz.getSuperclass().isSealed();
    boolean isAnyInterfaceSealed = false;
    for (Class<?> interfaceClass : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
      if (interfaceClass.isSealed()) {
        isAnyInterfaceSealed = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return (!isClassSealed && (isSuperSealed || isAnyInterfaceSealed)) && !Modifier.isFinal(clazz.getModifiers());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(NonSealedClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(NonSealedClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(SealedClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(SealedClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(FinalClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(FinalClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(OrdinaryClass.class) " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(OrdinaryClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(FinalSealedClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(FinalSealedClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(SubSealedClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(SubSealedClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(SubSubClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(SubSubClass.class));
    System.out.println("isExplicitlyNonSealed(ImplementingClass.class) = " + isExplicitlyNonSealed(ImplementingClass.class));
  }
}

sealed class SealedClass permits NonSealedClass, FinalSealedClass, SubSealedClass {}

non-sealed class NonSealedClass extends SealedClass {}

final class FinalClass {}

class OrdinaryClass {}

final class FinalSealedClass extends SealedClass {}

sealed class SubSealedClass extends SealedClass permits SubSubClass {}

non-sealed class SubSubClass extends SubSealedClass {}

sealed interface SealedInterface permits ImplementingClass {}

non-sealed class ImplementingClass implements SealedInterface {}
```

**Output:**

```bash
isExplicitlyNonSealed(NonSealedClass.class) = true
isExplicitlyNonSealed(SealedClass.class) = false
isExplicitlyNonSealed(FinalClass.class) = false
isExplicitlyNonSealed(OrdinaryClass.class) false
isExplicitlyNonSealed(FinalSealedClass.class) = false
isExplicitlyNonSealed(SubSealedClass.class) = false
isExplicitlyNonSealed(SubSubClass.class) = true
isExplicitlyNonSealed(ImplementingClass.class) = true
```

Comment: `clazz.getSuperclass()` brings in the parent hierarchy, isn't it?